# Symmetry of 2-nd degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Is every 2-nd degree polynomial symmetric about its extremum? I took the general 2-nd degree polynomial $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, computed $P'(x_0) = 0 => x_0 = -b/2a$, but then $P(x_0 + d)$ and $P(x_0 - d)$ are not equal.

Is this evidence against my hypothesis? It seems like it is, however I might have done a mistake, and in any case my intuition tells me that symmetry indeed exists. Like, every 2-nd degree polynomial I have seen in my life was symmetric. Can someone confirm or disprove this?

Comment: Check your calculation again. You will get $P(x_0+d)=P(x_0-d)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this by writing
$$P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a^2} + c$$
Getting rid of the vertical shift and scaling, this is just
$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$$
Which is indeed symmetric about the axis $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$

Comment: This makes absolute sense, thanks (although I am still trying to find the mistake in my calculations)

Comment: You'll have to post your calculations for me to find an error in them. In any case, performing this manipulation should give your answer fairly directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, a parabola is symmetric with respect to vertical reflections about the line $x = -b/2a$.

In fact, the computation you suggested works...

$\begin{align*}
P(x_0 + d) - P(x_0 - d) &= a((x_0+d)^2 - (x_0-d)^2) + b(2d) \\
&= a((x_0+d) - (x_0-d))((x_0+d) + (x_0 - d)) + 2bd \\
&= a(2d)(2x_0) + 2bd \\
&= -2bd + 2bd \\
&=0
\end{align*}$

Comment: I see, don't know why this didn't work for me... thanks!